# React Native socket.io client connecting successfully, but emits are not received on either end

Tags: sockets, react-native, socket.io

I'm trying to get communication working between a socket-io server and an iOS app. The devices connect according to both logs, but any `socket.emit()` actions from either the client or the server are not triggering the respective `.on()` event on the other end. Here is a minimal example that produces this problem.

Server code:

```
from aiohttp import web
import socketio

sio = socketio.AsyncServer()
app = web.Application()
sio.attach(app)

@sio.on('connect', namespace='/mp')
async def connect(sid, environ):
    print("connect ", sid)

@sio.on('chat message', namespace='/mp')
async def message(sid, data):
    print("message ", data)

@sio.on('disconnect', namespace='/mp')
def disconnect(sid):
    print('disconnect ', sid)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    web.run_app(app)
```

Client code (React Native app)

```
window.navigator.userAgent = 'ReactNative';
import React from "react"
import openSocket from "socket.io-client"
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, FlatList } from "react-native"
console.ignoredYellowBox = ["Remote debugger"]
import { YellowBox } from "react-native"
YellowBox.ignoreWarnings([
    "Unrecognized WebSocket connection option(s) `agent`, `perMessageDeflate`, `pfx`, `key`, `passphrase`, `cert`, `ca`, `ciphers`, `rejectUnauthorized`. Did you mean to put these under `headers`?"
])
var app = null
var socket = openSocket("http://localhost:8080/mp", {
            jsonp: false,
            reconnection: true,
            reconnectionDelay: 500,
            reconnectionAttempts: Infinity,
            transports: ["websocket"]
        })

export default class App extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        app = this

        socket.on("connect", function() {
            console.log("connected")
            socket.emit("message", "test")
        })

    }

    render() {
        app = this
        return (
            <View style={styles.container}>
                <Text>Open up App.js to start working on your app!</Text>
            </View>
        )
    }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        flex: 1,
        backgroundColor: "#fff",
        marginLeft:20,
        marginTop: 40,
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the issue was that I was sending event `message` to the server, but the server was listening for event `chat message` (I mixed up the event name and its function). Even then, server to client communication still doesn't work so I guess it's more debugging :P